# How to authorize access to Google Cloud Storage API in PHP, without the client library?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage

I want to access the Google Cloud Storage API directly with my own PHP code, because Google's API library is slow, but I can't figure out how to get authorization to work. See code below.

I am trying to list the files in a "directory" within a Google Cloud Storage bucket (i.e. get all the files with a certain prefix), in PHP code running on App Engine Standard. I found that the native PHP functions (e.g. scandir()) which are implemented to do this on AppEngine are horrifically slow (> 1 second). I'm not talking about huge directories either, maybe 10 files.

I also tried using the [Google APIs Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), specifically the [Objects](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.22.0/storage/bucket?method=objects) method, but found it to still be pretty slow, though not quite as bad, like around 0.5 seconds. The strange thing is, when I timed it, the actual "Objects()" call is fast, it's entering the loop ("foreach ($objects as $object)" - but just the first iteration) that's slow! So I think the library may be doing unnecessary work in processing the response. I verified this in ["Try this API"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list), looking at the request my browser makes, which takes < 100ms.

So, I want to make and process the API request directly, rather than using Google's slow library. This is the barebones function I wrote:

```
function get_files_from_gcs($dir, $data_storage_bucket) {
    $params = array(
        'delimiter' => '/',
        'prefix' => $dir,
        'fields' => 'items/name',);
    $query = http_build_query($params);
    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/" . $data_storage_bucket . "/o?" . $query;
    log_error('Curl URL:'  . $url);
    //  Initiate curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Execute
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    $filenames = array();
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if (array_key_exists('name', $item)) {
            $filenames[] = $item['name'];
        }
    }

    return $filenames;
}
```

However, I get an error message in the response:
"Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket ."

I have set public-read ACLs for my bucket like so:

```
gsutil defacl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://<MY BUCKET>
gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://<MY BUCKET>
```

And I also tried setting the 'project' URL param in my request, and/or creating an API Key and setting the 'key' param. No dice.

So I think I need to get an OAuth token (which I think is kind of silly - my App Engine Standard instance should be able to make requests to my GCS within the same project without any special authorization... but oh well). But honestly, I am pretty lost on how to do this. I've started looking through the Google Client API code, but I can't tell where this is actually happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You realize that Google APIs are rest APIs and there by run though a webserver.  You also need to remember that they all have flood protection.    If you go any faster that that your going to start getting 400 and 500 errors.

Comment: Right, in my question I specify that I tried the JSON API directly and found that it was significantly lower latency for a *single* request than Google's library. I don't need to make a lot of requests all at once, I just want to be able to make one with <500ms of latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, **you have a working solution**, but it's slow.

On that basis, I would suggest you use a hybrid approach. If you have auth working currently using the library, then keep that code without change. They key bit from the php documentation is:-

```
$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
$client->setAccessToken($token);
```

This is where you get the magical Access Token. Once you have that, you are free to construct your own http/rest calls. All you need to do is instantiate that Access Token into an http Authorization header, thus

> Authorization: "Bearer 4979e799a7979b79etc..."

Comment: Somehow I missed this years ago, and I'm no longer working on the code so I can't test it, but it seems like a really nice answer!